# HAProxy - Can I set a header on a monitor response?

Tags: haproxy

I want to set a custom header on the HAProxy monitor response. This is my test configuration file:

```
defaults
  mode  http
  timeout  client  300000
  timeout  server  300000
  timeout connect 5000

listen header_test
  bind  :60001
  mode http
  no log
  monitor-uri /
  http-response set-header My-Header some-value
```

According to the 1.8 [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4-http-response), `http-response` *is* supported inside a `listen` section. However, when I `GET /` using this config, I don't see my header:

```
➜  ~ curl -v localhost:60001
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:60001/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 60001 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:60001
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
<html><body><h1>200 OK</h1>
Service ready.
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0
```

I was able to see the header using a regular frontend/backend setup with the same `http-response` clause.

Is it valid to use `http-response` in a `listen` section with `monitor-uri`? If not, is there another way I can set a header on a monitor response?

Using HAProxy 1.8.3:

```
➜  ~ haproxy -v
HA-Proxy version 1.8.3-205f675 2017/12/30
Copyright 2000-2017 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not.

Monitor requests are processed in very early stage, there is no way to add headers to response of monitor requests.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: might help: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#monitor-uri